# Why does my web server software disallow PUT and DELETE requests?

Tags: http, rest

I am trying to implement a REST protocol and have realized in trying to debug that my web server is disallowing the `PUT` request.

I have tested and confirmed this further by running:

```
curl -X PUT  http://www.mywebserver.com/testpage
```

Which for my web server gives back a *403 - Forbidden error*.

The same happens for `DELETE`, where as for `POST` and `GET` everything is fine.

I am wondering if this is a common issue that those who use REST encounter and what the work-around might be?

Could I make a simple change to an `.htaccess` file?  Or do I need to modify the protocol to set a hidden variable "_method" in the POST query string?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Often web servers will be configured to block anything except GET and POST since
99% of the time they're all that are needed and there have been problems in the
past with applications assuming the requests were one of those two.

You don't say which server it is but, for example, you can tell Apache which
methods to allow with the  directive:

eg:

```
<Limit POST PUT DELETE>
  Require valid-user
</Limit>
```

It sounds like maybe some helpful sysadmin has used this to block non GET/POST

You could try an `.htaccess` with

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
  Allow from all
</Limit>
```

(I'm not an expert at apache, this may not be exactly correct)

Comment: I'll add that this works even if you can't seem to find *where* those methods are disabled. - ahem, just found it, in Debian it's in userdir.conf.

Comment: where should I put `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Limit directive docs: httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limit

Comment: Typically, you'd put the htaccess file in the root webserver directory because "...the directives apply to that directory, and all subdirectories thereof." -https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/q20206/howto/htaccess.html#what