# How to send DELETE request to phil sturgeon's - codeigniter-restserver

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

As the title says, I'm using Codeigniter with phil sturgeon - codeigniter-restserver framework.

I've followed the tutorial on [Nettus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/comment-page-3/#comments) and everything works fine Except when sending a DELETE request.

Code:

```
<?php
require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class Client extends REST_Controller{

function user_get()
{
    $data = array('returned:'=> $this->get('id'));
    $this->response($data);
}

function user_post()
{
    $data = array('returned:'=> $this->post('id'));
    $this->response($data);
}

function user_put()
{
    $data = array('returned:'=> $this->put('id'));
    $this->response($data);
}

function user_delete()
{
    $data = array('returned from delete:'=> $this->delete('id'));
    $this->response($data);
}
}
```

I'm using a FF Addon called HTTP Resource test, to send the request but when i send a DELETE request with this URL: `http://localhost/api/client/user/id/1`, I get {"returned from delete:":false}

**As a side note** : I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402229/web-server-that-does-not-allow-put-and-delete) and using the 'X-HTTP-Method-Override' header and sending it as a post request i was able to get the id, but I preffer a way where the client does not have to add this header.

Comment: +1 for the title "How to send DELETE request using phil sturgeon"

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I'll be sure to edit it :)

Comment: Check out this Gist: gist.github.com/Ema4rl/aebb63db1c76786c9cba811d69339fd3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According the the HTTP spec DELETE cannot send parameters. It can have things in the URL, so you could change this to:

```
public function user_delete($id)
{
    $this->response(array(
        'returned from delete:' => $id,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Phil, great FW by the way :). So i guess the tutorial on Nettuts is not updated since the code is from there. Also the url should be : http://localhost/api/client/user/1 (remove the /id/)

Comment: just a comment, but shouldn't you use something more like `localhost/api/client/user/delete/1` or something?

Comment: ftom2: The internet is an archive, not every article is maintained forever and I couldn't do that if I wanted to.

Comment: Mike: Why would you do that? Twitter has tainted peoples minds of what a REST API is. Adding "delete" is not only overly verbose (a HTTP Header called "DELETE" is already doing that) but is masively insecure. If you use any GET available URL for destructive actions then you open yourself up to a whole world of ridiculous security problems - and accidental deletion of content.

Comment: Thanks @PhilSturgeon - your library has been very useful to me. I hope they do update that tute sooner rather than later, because it's probably frustrating more than a few ppl.

Comment: The article definitely will not be updated, it is years old and explains how the software worked at the time. This unfortunately is how most tutorials work. Also, this was not an error with the docs, but user error. :)

Comment: Thanks @PhilSturgeon - your library is really very useful. I am processing the same request for delete and got nothing to display. I searched a lot and finally found this but it is not working for me.I am doing same process as you told.

Comment: Check out this Gist: https://gist.github.com/Ema4rl/aebb63db1c76786c9cba811d69339fd3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem an this work for me

**1 -> in REST_Controller.php** replace the default _parse_delete() function by :

```
protected function _parse_delete()
{
    $this->_delete_args = $_DELETE;
    $this->request->format and $this->request->body = file_get_contents('php://input');
    // Set up out DELETE variables (which shouldn't really exist, but sssh!)
    parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $this->_delete_args);
}
```

That's all! no more need of  " *user_delete(**$id**)* ""

Comment: Check out this Gist: gist.github.com/Ema4rl/aebb63db1c76786c9cba811d69339fd3