# PUT method inside Laravel Controller

Tags: php, rest, laravel

I can't seem to assign a function inside my controller for a PUT action. I tried a PUT request on `/settings` but I got a 403 Forbidden.

I've declared `Route::controller('settings', 'SettingsController')` in `routes.php`:

```
<?php
class SettingsController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex() {
        $setting = Auth::user()->setting;
        return Response::json($setting);
    }

    public function putIndex() {
        $setting = Auth::user()->setting;
        $setting->update(Input::all());
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post your 'form' view code that you are using for the index?

Comment: Hi. I'm actually building a RESTful API for apps.. So I'm not using any form. I'm testing it using curl :  curl -i http://my.domain.co.uk/settings --user freemanon@x.com:12345678 -v --data {"a":"1"} -X PUT

Comment: Probably your web server is blocking PUT requests? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1402229/1317935

Comment: Thx a lot! It worked :) Put it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your web server is blocking PUT requests?

[Why does my web server software disallow PUT and DELETE requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1402229/1317935)

This means that when you try and do a PUT the server returns the 403.