# why PUT and DELETE requests not working on remote server and how to solve it?

Tags: php, .htaccess, angularjs, rest

I an experimenting REST with AngularJS and PHP (codeigniter with rest library).

I have tried both $http and Restangular for REST requests but PUT and DELETE requests throws 403 forbidden on remote server(using byethost free php server) whereas on local server it works fine.

Do i need to enable it or something?

After reading [Why does my web server software disallow PUT and DELETE requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402229/why-web-servers-does-not-allow-put-and-delete)
I added

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
  Allow from all
</Limit>
```

to .htaccess now PUT is working fine but DELETE request fails

Comment: Did you find any solution?