# laravel resource and angular http

Tags: angularjs, rest, laravel

Blog - RESTful Resource Controller

route to the controller Blog

```
Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController');
```

Simple query does not work

```
$http.delete('/blog/1');
```

return

> 403 Forbidden

POST(store), GET (index, show), requests work

delete (destroy) does not work

```
$http.post('/blog/1', {_method: 'DELETE'});
```

return

> 405 Method Not Allowed

```
<?php

class BlogController extends \BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        return Blog::orderBy('id')->get();
    }

    public function store()
    {
        ....
        ....
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        return Blog::find($id);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Blog::destroy($id);
    }


}
```

Comment: can you post your controller file

Comment: Is that API and the APP on the same domain ? or are you performing a Cross Origin Request

Comment: Check your network tab for the request headers section to see what it's sending exactly, is the method actual being set as DELETE.  I've used $resource with a Slim PHP backend and it's worked out fine using .$delete on items pulled from the server, if the default setup doesn't work you can customize what is sent like $http({'method':'DELETE', url:'/blog/1'}) typically a $resource works well with RESTful CRUD though.

Comment: 403 Forbidden

http://c2n.me/j5xqwO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some web servers may block http delete method.
if you use Apache, try to allow it. Add this code to your .htaccess file:

```
<Limit GET POST DELETE>
  Allow from all
</Limit>
```

Similar problem was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402229/why-web-servers-does-not-allow-put-and-delete)

Hope this helps :)