# Javascript PHP PUT Method returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

If I run a POST or GET method it runs fine but if I use PUT then I keep getting `403 Forbidden` returned. I'm not sure why its doing this and was hoping someone could help me out.

**AngularJS**

```
var id = {
    "locationData": locationData,
    "userData": userData,
    "url": url
}
$http({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: '/api/user',
    data: {
        'data': id
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
}).success(function(content, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.url = data;
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/assets/modals/modal-url.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl4,
        resolve: {
            url: function() {
                return $scope.url;
            }
        },
        scope: $scope.$new()
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/api/db_connect.php');

if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathFragments = explode('/', $path);
$id = end($pathFragments);

switch (strtoupper($method)) {

    case "PUT":
        $postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $src = (array)$postdata->data;

        echo "PUT";

        break;
    case "GET":

        $postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $src = (array)$postdata->data;

        echo "GET";

        break;
    case "POST":

        $postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $src = (array)$postdata->data;

        echo "POST";

        break;
    case "DELETE":
        echo "Your favorite color is green!";

        break;
    default:
        echo "Your favorite color is neither red, blue, or green!";
}
```

Comment: Why are you making a PUT request with `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` data and then trying to decode it as JSON?

Comment: Have you allowed your script to use the PUT Method? Show us your config line for that. Make sure the Patch is correct

Comment: What does the server logs say? They usually tell you why they are forbidding access.

Comment: Similar question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402229/why-web-servers-does-not-allow-put-and-delete)

Comment: A `403`  means something like cross domain security issues. PUT, and DEL are often blocked. So you should check permissions, maybe blocked by webserver.  It does not have much to do with the actual content or erroneous request, this would've been a `400` or `405`.