# HttpWebRequest- Deletion "Method Not Allowed."

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to delete a remote image using WebRequest (specifically through http) 
 but I'm getting the following **error message** :

```
"The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.".
```

This is the code that I'm using...

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/TestImage/5045.jpg");
webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile; // "DELETE";
HttpWebResponse httpReponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```

Please advice...
thanks.

Comment: Do you control that webserver? It seems it really doesn't like the `DELETE` method.

Comment: I believe deleting files via HTTP isn't possible.

Comment: VJS is right. You cannot delete via HTTP. However you can delete via an FTP system. These are fairly easy to set up as well.

Comment: @VJS, @Jonny: No, you *can* delete via HTTP if the webserver or the backing webapp supports (and allows) it. `DELETE` is a valid HTTP verb.

Comment: See also: [RFC 7231, section 4.3.5](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.5)

Comment: Hi, I am working on lines with this msdn link, per which we can delete using html: [link](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/314193)

Comment: @DaSourcerer, I can suggest changes to webserver if that would solve the case...please advice.

Comment: @user1705851: It would help to know which webserver you are using. For Apache, see http://serverfault.com/questions/438183/how-to-enable-all-http-methods-in-an-apache-http-server and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402229/why-web-servers-does-not-allow-put-and-delete

Comment: @DaSourcerer, I'm using a Windows server. (Thanks for your replies)

Comment: @user1705851: Meaning? You're on Microsoft's IIS?