# In Apache servers DELETE requests treated as GET how to fix it?

Tags: php, apache, rest, laravel

I have a REST api built with Laravel. in the routes I added:

```
DELETE /v1/category/{category} App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController@destroy
```

On my local machine which has `xampp` every thing works fine and the `destroy` method is triggered. but on the production server when I request that route it treats it as `GET` request and return the record of that category instead of deleting it.

To go around the issue I avoided using `DELETE` requests so I registered the route as:

```
GET /v1/category/delete/{category} App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController@destroy
```

Any Ideas why the `DELETE` request treated as `GET`?

> **Update:** Here is the routes.php file:

```
<?php

    /**
     * Api Route Group V1
     */
    RestRoute::group(['version' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function () {

        RestRoute::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {

            RestRoute::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController');

            RestRoute::get('posts/user/{id}', 'PostsController@userPosts');
            RestRoute::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
            RestRoute::resource('items', 'ItemsController');

            RestRoute::get('recipes/all', 'RecipesController@showAll');
            RestRoute::resource('recipes', 'RecipesController');
            RestRoute::resource('profile', 'ProfileController');

            RestRoute::get('tag', 'TagsController@index');
            RestRoute::get('tag/{tag}', 'TagsController@show');
            RestRoute::get('tag/{tag}/articles', 'TagsController@tagArticles');


            RestRoute::post('category', 'CategoriesController@store');
            RestRoute::get('category/list', 'CategoriesController@CategoriesList');
            RestRoute::get('category/recipes/{category}', 'CategoriesController@showRecipes');
            RestRoute::get('category/{category}', 'CategoriesController@show');
            RestRoute::patch('category/{category}', 'CategoriesController@update');
            RestRoute::delete('category/{category}', 'CategoriesController@destroy');


            RestRoute::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
            RestRoute::get('authenticate/logout', 'AuthenticateController@logout');
            RestRoute::post('register', 'AuthenticateController@store');

        });

    });
```

Comment: Can you post your routes file code

Comment: What web server is running on the production server? Apache2 or nginx? Would probably need to see you conf file for the site.

Comment: I Updated the question with the `routes.php` file. note that on `Test` server  on my local machine the code is working fine

Comment: I'm using `Apache` server

Comment: @Pitchinnate You might want to look at the question tags.

Comment: Most Apache-caused problems are fixed by removing it and using nginx :)

Comment: Yea that kinda true .. but I'm using Apache on both local machine and production server and everything works fine on my local machine.

Comment: The backslashes are for the name space that how its done in PHP this not a URL.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402229/why-does-my-web-server-software-disallow-put-and-delete-requests) out. You need to configure Apache to actually understand PUT / DELETE / PATCH requests. It's a dumb server with a bad architecture, using silly mod_php on top of everything (even though it can speak FastCGI, for some reason people don't use it).

Comment: Had such issues caused by frontend frameworks. I solved it with method spoofing: Add to your request: eg _method=DELETE

Comment: I did something like that but by changing the route in Laravel to be `category/delete/{id}` and send it as GET instead of `category/{id}` and send it as DELETE, but I need to find the cause of the issue not a work around.

Comment: @N.B. That was helpful I will check with the system admin to see if that was the issue.