# Laravel route method DELETE not working

Tags: laravel-5

In my `routes.php`, when I have:

```
    Route::delete('page/{id}', function ($id)
    {
        return "deleting $id";
    });
```

And I send a `delete` or `get` request using Postman, This throws a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`.

When I change `routes.php`:

```
    Route::get('page/{id}', function ($id)
    {
        return "deleting $id";
    });
```

It responds the string `deleting...` in response to `GET`, `DELETE` and `PUT`! 
But the HTTP code is 403.

It just throws a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` on a `POST` request.

This problem seems to occur only on remote server and it works as expected on localhost.

Is there anything in Laravel that maybe redirects or changes methods to `GET`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Apache doesn't allow `DELETE` requests, and that's why the response code is a "403 forbidden".

Add this to `.htaccess` after the Laravel default codes:

```
<Limit DELETE>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Limit>
```

see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1402480/2543240

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your form, above delete button:

```
{!! method_field('DELETE') !!}
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
```