# Laravel DELETE operation returns 403

Tags: laravel

I am hosting a Laravel application purchased from codecanyon using VPS hosting under a subdomain

https://mobile.tastebud.com.my/

Laravel project folders are located /public_html/mobile - subfolder.

Laravel version - VERSION = '5.8.38';

This application API is called from flutter mobile application

Now it seems most of the things is working, except DELETE (so far I found it) API request is being rejected with 403 Forbidden

[image: Get request]

[image: Failed Post request]

[image: HTTP header]

Content of  "/public_html/mobile/public/.htaccess"

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  
</IfModule>
```

**Any clue what is wrong ? or at least where can I find more information to investigate further **

I have tried this

[Why does my web server software disallow PUT and DELETE requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402229/why-does-my-web-server-software-disallow-put-and-delete-requests/)

[Laravel route method DELETE not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531124/laravel-route-method-delete-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.This has to be added into apache vhost file
**Require all granted**

```
<Directory "/home/tastebud/public_html/mobile">
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
    SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>
```

This did the work

Comment: Can you share location for vhost file ?