# Cakephp 3 : Giving 403 Forbidden error for put

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am using cakephp 3.3.2 version and 5.6 php version.

My edit action look like

```
public function edit($id = null) {
        $country = $this->Countries->get($id, [
                'contain' => []
            ]);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $country = $this->Countries->patchEntity($country, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Countries->save($country)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The country has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The country could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('country'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['country']);
    }
```

This code working fine in localhost, But in my real host (using share host) it's giving me 403 Forbidden error, when I am going to edit something. Then I have used postman to check. Then I have seen it's working fine for get and post , but giving  403 Forbidden error for put. Have there any extra settings in php or cakephp for solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you said it's working on localhost so it could be server issue..
check this approved answer-
[Why does my web server software disallow PUT and DELETE requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402229/why-does-my-web-server-software-disallow-put-and-delete-requests) answer

Comment: I am using share hosting here.So it may need to change .htaccess but no idea how to add this setting in cakephp htaccess.

Comment: I'm relatively new to cakephp.. can you try the limit code in htaccess and check if it helps?as far as i know the limit condition will be limited to the folder containing the htaccess file so you might want to try in the base folder as well as src..

Comment: I deny put method and apply post define post method in all form, then my problem has been solved. For security it may some server not accept put method. I am accepting your ans because it have given me a direction to solve this issue.