# DELETE and PUT does not recognize even after adjusting all required apache configurations

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I have a Laravel app that I recently uploaded on the server.

From [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1402480/498504) I found that I should add these to end of `htaccess` file (after all laravel configurations) in `public` directory:

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
  Allow from all
</Limit>
```

But server can not recognize requests that sent via **PUT** or **DELETE** methods and shows this error :

```
501
Not Implemented

The requested method is not implemented by the server.
```

Apache version is **2.2.31** and operating system is **linux**.

What is problem and does remain something that I should be add?

**Update:**

This is a part of my routes related to issue:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'post'], function () {
    Route::resource('/category', 'CategoryController');
});
```

In the other hand I used a `$.delete` user defined function like this to send `DELETE` requests:

```
$.delete = function (url, data, callback, type) {

        if ($.isFunction(data)) {
            type = type || callback,
                callback = data,
                data = {}
        }

        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: callback,
            data: data,
            dataType: type
        });
    }
```

And I used it to delete a category by it's ID:

```
$.delete('http://mysite.ir/post/category/20'+ , {}, function (res) {
    // console.log(res);
}, 'json');
```

And `destroy` method that delete selected category:

```
public function destroy ($id, Request $request)
{
    Category::destroy($id);
    return ['success' => true, 'msg' => 'category removed.'];
}
```

Comment: What error do you get if you remove that Limit rule?

Comment: @DusanBajic,same `501 Not Implemented` error.

Comment: Are this methods implemented in your app?

Comment: yes, I used those methods along with that rule on the other servers and work fine. but I changed my server and I have that problem.

Comment: Can you show the code in which way you're sending the requests to the server??

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi, please see update.

Answer (score 0):

It might be something you also need to change in your apache config file?

Comment: What configurations I must to change ?